# Update App Metadata in Appstore

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app to store, and it came in Appstore. After that i need to change the name which appears above my app when iam looking in itunes in device and also want to edit © name of app which resides  bottom left corner in appstore. I marked it in below image, where can i update it? in App metadata? or store account? or both? please help.

[image]

Comment: Which do you need to change? These are two completely different bits of information.

Comment: app review info contains developer name, right?

Comment: The app review info is not visible to anyone except the person reviewing an app.

Comment: it is my app and i can see it when i login to app account..

Comment: That's all done when you submit an app update. It's part of the app's meta data in iTunes Connect. But it has nothing to do with the app review notes.

Comment: ok fine, how can i change it now?

Comment: You can't change the current app. The can only update it as part of an app update. Read the FAQ in iTunes Connect.

Comment: iam ready to update my app, any how i want to change it.,

Comment: So change it. Just do it before you actually submit the binary.

Comment: @rmaddy: then, what are the fields which came in above round marked text.

Comment: Go through the steps of adding the update to your app. It will be pretty clear what you need to change when you get to the screen in iTunes Connect.

Comment: @rmaddy: one more thing, do i need to change anything in my store account for the above purpose? or need to update only appmeta data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copyright text is a property you can change with each version of your app in iTunes Connect. Select your app, click "View Details" for the version you'd like to change, then click "Edit" next to Version Information, and you'll be presented with this popup:
[image: Version Information screen in iTunes Connect]

As for changing the display name for your apps, you'll need to [contact Apple directly](https://developer.apple.com/contact/). Note that as an individual (non-business) developer, this must be your actual name. If you have a business/company and would like your apps to be under this name, you'll have to contact Apple and present your business documentation to prove its existence. Even when registered as a business, however, you're still limited to using your business name or a trading name - with minor variations allowed (for example "Apple" rather than "Apple, Inc.", as lnjuanj has pointed out).

Comment: Nearly correct. The name that is displayed doesn't need to meet the company name, at least exactly. As an example, Apple Inc shows as Apple alone. You may select a name and I have seen names very different from the company name. But the all the res in the answer t is correct.

Comment: That's true, I suppose my point was just that having a business account wasn't a free pass to choose whatever name you felt like. :)

Comment: Could you correct your answer with this info so I could upvote it? It is a very good one.